Checking HDD drives for physical errors - scanning sectors
I'm using Windows 11 Pro and wanting to check my new 4TB SATA3 Hard Drive (single NTFS partition of usable 3.63 TB) plugged by Natec Kangaroo Dual. The drive shows up correctly as a ejectable device.
I want to test this device before I start using it for my files. Before I used HDTune free for scanning HDDs for sector errors, but it doesn't support drives bigger than 2TB. The trial version of HDTune Pro supports 4TB, but it doesn't allow you to check the whole disk for the errors. I'm not willing to pay ca. 30USD for the Pro license to do one-time check.
Is there another a way to conduct a full scan for physical errors and issues of a 4TB drive?

The OEM of the drive typically has tools for this. You could also just use chkdsk with the /R option. This is built into windows and will check for (and repair) bad sectors.

A SMART Extended or Long test will read every sector of the drive. Note that "sector errors" are mostly only detected during a read operation, i.e. the ECC is used to validate the data read. So there's typically no reason to first require a sector write. IOW a write-read-verify of each sector is going to take a lot longer, and not likely to produce different scan results.

As @Silbee mentioned in the comments, the way to go about it in Windows 11 is:

Run command line (cmd) as administrator
From there, run chkdsk command with /R option (e.g. chkdsk G: /r)

In previous versions default disk checker (GUI) on Windows had an explicit option (a checkbox) to run in-depth scan, now (from what I can gather) it's only available in command line when running chkdsk.

You may want to do a smartctl on the drive before and after the chkdsk /r to see how many previously undetected errors now exist.

Will this check the whole disk? Or just the partition with the filesystem? (even with a single partition of max size there are still sectors not assigned to it). Or just the fragment used by the filesystem? (in general a filesystem may be smaller than its partition).

@KamilMaciorowski as far as I can gather - this checks only selected partition.


Prior to using, all mechanical drives should have a burn-in test performed, which is done via a long S.M.A.R.T test.
In addition to this, Short and Long S.M.A.R.T tests should be regulalry performed on mechanical drives (can be configured via Task Scheduler [TaskSchd.msc]):

Regular S.M.A.R.T tests are to ensure drive hardware integrity, whereas redundancy and filesystem error detection is to ensure data integrity (these are two parts of the same whole) 


Burn-in Test:
smartctl commands are the same across OSes

Download and install smartmontools
Open an Admin terminal: +R → Open: powershell → Ctrl+Shift+OK
Add smartmontools to $Path → Re-open terminal:
# Windows requires closing and re-opening terminal to reload $Path:
  Cmd /c Setx /M Path "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\smartmontools\bin;"; exit

Cmd | Setx 
Get disk info for running smartctl:
# smartctl uses <disk> identifiers: sda, sdb, ...

# Match drive serial numbers to their drive letter mountpoints:
  $drive = (Get-PSDrive).Name -match '^[c-z]$'
  $disk = 'a'..'z'

  ""; Foreach ($letter in $drive) {
    Write-Host $letter': ' -nonewline
    Get-Partition -DriveLetter $letter | Get-Disk
  }

# Match with drive letter mount points: (once blank entries are returned: Ctrl+C)
  ""; ForEach ($letter in $disk) {
    Write-Host sd$letter (smartctl -a /dev/sd$letter | Select-String "Device Model")
    Write-Host "   " (smartctl -a /dev/sd$letter | Select-String "Serial Number"); ""

    # To also list amount of time for a Long test, uncomment:
    ## Write-Host "     " (smartctl -a /dev/sd$letter | Select-String "Extended self-test routine")
    ## Write-Host "     " (smartctl -a /dev/sd$letter | Select-String "recommended polling time:" | Select-Object -last 1); ""
  }

ForEach | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-PSDrive | Select-Object |Select-String |Write-Host 
Run Long S.M.A.R.T test:
smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>

# Check progress:
  smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | Select-String "test remaining" -Context 1,0



Once test completes, check output for errors:
smartctl -a /dev/<disk>



If no errors are found: no further testing required 


If Errors are Found:

Review:

Hardware error section to determine at what power on hours error occurred at
SMART Attributes with Thresholds values within Examples section
Bad block HowTo


Ensure filesystem corruption doesn't exist:

Non-OS Partitions:
# Auto-dismounts the partition:
  ChkDsk <DriveLetter>: /OfflineScanAndFix


OS Partition: Boot WinRE so output can be seen
# Boot WinRE:
  Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0

  # Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt

  # Ascertain OS partition's drive letter (it's usually not C:):
    DiskPart → lis vol → exit

  # Check filesystem:
    ChkDsk <DriveLetter>: /OfflineScanAndFix

ChkDsk | DiskPart | Shutdown  




The more critical the data, such as that on servers, the more often S.M.A.R.T tests should be run to ensure the drives themselves don't have hardware damage (cases get bumped/moved, etc.)

To not regularly test a drive for hardware damage is like brushing your teeth but not going to the dentist - it's not advised, as these are two parts of the same whole; I believe it's a good idea for mechanical drives to be tested:

Non-Servers: Short every ~7 - 15d | Long every ~15 - 30d  (what I did prior to switching to all SSDs) 
Servers: Short every 1 - 7d | Long every 7 - 15d  (what I've done on my NAS since ~2015)  Opinions regarding frequency:  In a decade of running TrueNAS (FreeNAS before the name change), the consistent advice from developers and users has been twice monthly long tests at a minimum. I trust the consistent, repeated recommendations of TrueNAS developers and users when TrueNAS is used on millions of servers and by the majority of Fortune 500 companies. 




Examples:

Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   043   043   000    Old_age   Always       -       24972
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   187   187   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 16/46)

  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0



SMART Self-Test Log Structure:
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     24885         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     24765         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     24643         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     24523         -



Error output will resemble:
ATA Error Count: 2

  CR = Command Register         [HEX]
  FR = Features Register        [HEX]
  SC = Sector Count Register    [HEX]
  SN = Sector Number Register   [HEX]
  CL = Cylinder Low Register    [HEX]
  CH = Cylinder High Register   [HEX]
  DH = Device/Head Register     [HEX]
  DC = Device Command Register  [HEX]
  ER = Error register           [HEX]
  ST = Status register          [HEX]

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 403 hours (16 days + 19 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    40 51 08 28 d5 00 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0000d528 = 54568

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    c8 00 08 28 d5 00 e0 08   1d+10:18:07.310  READ DMA
    ca 00 08 e8 a1 12 e0 08   1d+10:18:06.830  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 c8 fa 11 e0 08   1d+10:18:06.830  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 00 f7 11 e0 08   1d+10:18:06.830  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 b8 f1 11 e0 08   1d+10:18:06.830  WRITE DMA

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 369 hours (15 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    10 51 08 10 17 35 e0  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x00351710 = 3479312

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    ca 00 08 10 17 35 e0 08      03:35:59.609  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 60 16 35 e0 08      03:35:59.609  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 20 11 35 e0 08      03:35:59.607  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 08 11 35 e0 08      03:35:59.607  WRITE DMA
    ca 00 08 b0 10 35 e0 08      03:35:59.607  WRITE DMA




That is an absolutely insane schedule for running self-tests. Especially for servers, the correct answer is disk-level or machine-level redundancy and error detection (bonus if you use a filesystem with integrity hashing like ZFS or ReFS), not constantly scheduling S.M.A.R.T. self-tests. Rather, you would do a filesystem-level scrub that can actually verify the data returned.

I'll also note that the 'long' self-test will often fail on modern drives if you run it while fully idle, in a default OS configuration. The typical workaround is a little script that just touches a file on the drive every few minutes to keep it awake.

@Bob I run TrueNAS on my server, which ZFS is the default filesystem of. S.M.A.R.T tests are to verify the hardware is fine, whereas redundancy and scrubs are to verify the software and data is fine. Anyone running a TrueNAS server does a burn-in test of mechanical drives before importing them into their pools, and there are several write-ups on the TrueNAS forum covering this in-depth. I've never had a long S.M.A.R.T test fail on any drive when fully idle, TrueNAS or otherwise (long tests should be scheduled when the drive is fully idle)

@JW0914 Possible failure is dependent on specifics of the drive firmware and what the OS configures for power management. Some cheaper drives don’t consider a running SMART self test as something that should keep the drive awake if told to do aggressive power management. And as far as hardware versus data, for a lot of people just covering the data is good enough (it’s statistically very unlikely for a sector that you are not actively interacting with to go bad, so unless you’re operating at a massive scale or need absolute data safety without backups you can largely ignore that possibility).

@AustinHemmelgarn Most drives placed in a server (e.g, NAS or Video drives for use in surveillance systems) do not have that issue, and when running a server, such as a NAS, most want to know if their drives are failing. This is not my opinion, it's the norm - TrueNAS is used by millions of consumers (incl. myself since 2015) and a majority of Fortune 500 companies, with this concept being so paramount, its functionality is built directly into the OS for management from the WebUI. Knowing when a drive is beginning to fail is when to replace it, not after.

@AustinHemmelgarn Here's a common scenario: a person buys 8x new mechanical NAS drives for their 8bay server. Drives are known to have a higher chance of failure after ~4yrs and by choosing to not run regular short and long S.M.A.R.T tests, the person has no idea if their drives have any hardware issues or if they're beginning to fail (most consumers don't take the route of corporations who replace their drives en masse ~4yr mark, whether they're failing or not, as it's not economical). It's not uncommon to have same-age drives begin to fail around the same time or fail after several months.

My second comment was more general for running 'long' tests. Recall that we are on a site where users are not necessarily running servers, and the OP here is using a USB dock - NAS/server drives can not be assumed. I've certainly observed long tests failing due to drives going to sleep. As far as tests, the typical advice I've seen is to monitor the S.M.A.R.T. data (which smartd does by default when installed on many distros, w/ mail alerts), not to necessarily run tests.

If your long selftests get aborted, consider using select selftests instead. It's like the long selftest, only split into smaller segments, resumable, suitable to run daily and still cover entire drive every X days. Also works for machines that don't run 24/7…
